# Function extreme points

Tags: functions

I have this function:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} |x-1| & x \text{ is real $\{0,2\}$}
 \\   0 & x=2 \end{cases} $$

Whats the number of extreme points for this function and which are they?The derivate looks like this: $f'(x)=1$, $x>1$,$-1< x<1$ and $0$ $x=2$.Shouldn't the derivate be =0 in extreme points? so this would mean only 2 is an extreme point

Comment: What does it mean if the function fails to be differentiable somewhere in the domain?

Comment: it doesn't have any extreme points?

Comment: Every function over a closed interval has extreme points. Candidates for extreme points are the end points, stationary points (where the derivative is 0), and points where the derivative does not exist.  You have an important point that you are missing, where the derivative does not exist.

Comment: I've edited your post to show how to do the formatting I *think* you mean to do; check that I've done it correctly and if not edit to fix it.

Comment: Aside: what does "$x$ is real{0,2}" mean?

Answer (score 0):

this function is not derivablie beacuse left derivative in 1 is not equal with right derivative in 1 
but you dont need derivative to find extreme point this funtction have a minimal value f(x)=0 because |x-1|>=0 for any x and for x=1 f(x)=0
if x can take just this value: 0 and 2 than we canot speack about extreme value